# How can I create a database table via doctrine in Symfony 4?

Tags: mysql, symfony, user-interface, doctrine, entity

In Symfony I created an entity:

src/Entity/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=254, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }
}
```

After that I wanted to create the database table via terminal:

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

But I get a lot of error messages:

> Migration 20180628135528 failed during Execution. Error An exception
>   occurred while executing 'CREATE TAB LE app_users (id INT
>   AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, password
>   VARCHAR(64) NOT NUL L, email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, is_active
>   TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_C2502824F85E0677 (userna me),
>   UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_C2502824E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT
>   CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE u tf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
>   was too long; max key length is 767  bytes
>
> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 125:
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE app_users (id
>   INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, usern   ame VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
>   password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, is_active
>   TINY   INT(1) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_C2502824F85E0677 (username),
>   UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_C2502824E7927C74 (   email), PRIMARY KEY(id))
>   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE =
>   InnoDB':
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified
>   key was too long; max key length i   s 767 bytes
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 109:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified
>   key was too long; max key length i   s 767 bytes
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 107:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified
>   key was too long; max key length i   s 767 bytes

Comment: Do you use Mysql? The max string length there is 191 and your email is configured as 254.

Comment: It has generally nothing to do with mysql but much more with the used storage engine (MyISAM / InnoDB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=254, unique=true)
 */
private $email;
```

Change to max length of 191 (which should be plenty enough for email ... )

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
 */
private $email;
```

Or change your storage engine ...

Comment: I even tried `app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result`

Comment: It was finally working when I removed all Migration Versions

Comment: Problem commes from new Symfony defaults charset and collation which is now `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`. Going back to `utf8` will solve the problem without need to lower the string length. BUT utf8mb4 is supposed to solve special characters problems so choose the best option for your needs.